# Incorrect values returned when checking neighbours surrounding coordinate in 2d vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Having a weird issue with the results of my code. Basically I have a sprite, and I create a "hitbox" of this sprite by checking the alpha value of each pixel and storing the result in a 2d vector of boolean values, where a pixel of alpha 0 = false and any other value = true. My test case presented here is a 10x10 pixel square with no transparent pixels. Representing the value of each coordinate in this 2d array as either a 1 (true) or 0 (false) results in the following:

```
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
```

This 2d vector is called "hitBox". My code is meant to check each coordinate in hitBox to see if it returns "true" (with the exception of the coordinates representing the outermost pixels of the sprite), and if returns true each of the coordinate's neighbours are checked to see if they return "true" also. If all neighbours return true the value of the corresponding coordinate of "hitBox2" (which starts off as a copy of hitBox) is changed from "true" to "false". Direct copy of the code used for this is as follows:

```
vector<vector<bool> > hitBox2;
hitBox2 = hitBox;
for (int i = 1; i < sprite.getLocalBounds().height - 1; ++i) //i starts at 1 to avoid checking edge tiles, check is < height - 1 for same reason
{
    for (int j = 1; j < sprite.getLocalBounds().width - 1; ++j)
    {
        if(hitBox[i][j])
        {
            if (hitBox[i - 1][j - i] &&
                hitBox[i - 1][j] &&
                hitBox[i - 1][j + 1] &&
                hitBox[i][j - 1] &&
                hitBox[i][j + 1] &&
                hitBox[i + 1][j - 1] &&
                hitBox[i + 1][j] &&
                hitBox[i + 1][j + 1])
                    hitBox2[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

sprite.getLocalBounds().height and .width return the height and width in pixels of the sprite as an int. As far as I can tell this should result in hitBox2 ending up as follows:

```
1111111111
1        1
1        1
1        1
1        1
1        1
1        1
1        1
1        1
1111111111
```

But instead hitBox2 comes out of this as the following:

```
1111111111
1        1
1        1
11       1
111      1
1111     1
1 111    1
1  111   1
11  111  1
1111111111
```

I cannot figure out why this code does not give the result I intended. I'm assuming I made a typo or logical error somewhere, but for the life of me I cannot find it! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `sprite.getLocalBounds()` parts with `10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      if (hitBox[i - 1][j - i] && /*...*/
```

The 2nd index is wrong. It should be `j - 1` instead of `j - i`. See http://ideone.com/kY2MMy for the result after fixing this place.

Comment: Dayum. Checking this code since 10 minutes, how could I miss that... But `hitBox[i - 1][j - i]` will always return true since it will give 0, so it's not the problem.

Comment: @Mayerz @Proply Anyway it works after I change it from `j-i` to `j-1` as shown in http://ideone.com/kY2MMy

Comment: Okay, but wait, `hitBox[i - 1][j - i]` will always be true right?

Comment: @Mayerz `hitBox[i-1][j-i]` leads to out-of-bound access when `i > j`.

Comment: Idd, my bad! Was stuck in the 10x10 example.

Comment: And that's why it looks buggy only in later rows.

Comment: Typo it is! Thankyou!